# count consecutive positive or negative number in php array values

Tags: php, arrays

Thanks in advance 
i have an PHP array

```
array( -1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1 );
```

I want a php code for adding the consecutive integer otherwise just print as  it 
i need the result like `-1,4,-2,3,-1,1,-4,3,-2,1,-3,7,-1` as string

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array( -1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1 );
$result = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $k=>$v) {
   if(($v < 0 && $i <=0) || ($v > 0 && $i >=0)) {
      $i+=$v;
   } else {
      $result[] = $i;
      $i=$v;
   }
}
$result[] = $i;
var_dump($result);
```